# weird while loop in c sockets?

Tags: c, linux, unix, while-loop, conditional-statements

i have these loop in client server model ,but these loop in **Client** code is to read from file until the file is 0 or EOF but but its never enter the loop even the condition is true ???

```
int n_read;

while ( (   n_read=((read(sockfd,&buffer,sizeof(buffer))))>0    )   );
{
    printf("test to print\n");
    write(fd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    //bzero(&buffer,sizeof(buffer));


}
```

and the weird thing is i have same loop in **Server** Code to read and write from file
and its work perfect but i dont know why in client does not work as server ???

Here is server loop code :

```
while (( read(fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer)))>0) /* to read from open file descriptor */
                         {
                            n=write(connfd,&buffer,n);
                             if(n<0){error("Error,Reading from socket \n");}     
                            {buffer[n] = '\0';}
                         }
```

so,how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a semi-colon at the end of the line in the client code.

```
while ( (   n_read=((read(sockfd,&buffer,sizeof(buffer))))>0    )   );
                                                                     ^
```

That's consider the whole loop.  You won't execute the following code until it is false and then only once before falling through.

You also went a bit nuts with parentheses.  You can reduce it to

```
while ((n_read = read(sockfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Advice: Never put a ";" (semicolon) after a while/for loop cuddled against the right-paren.  You really want a coding style that either places the semicolon on its own line, or better place {} (braces) after every loop.

*Some people like the cuddled-else approach to avoid just this problem.*

*I prefer {} under the loop keywords, and clean ) at end of line.*

Please show your declarations for buffer in both programs.  In one you provide &buffer (address of buffer), while in the other you provide only buffer.  Likely your buffer is already declared as a pointer or array, and so the '&' is causing problems.

Because sockets are happy to carry binary, you may want to ensure you terminate any cstring you receive, for example,

```
int n_read;
while ( (n_read=read(sockfd,&buffer,sizeof(buffer))) >0 )
{
    buffer[n_read]='\0';
    printf("test to print, %s\n",buffer);
    write(fd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
}
```